# datetimepicker not showing calendar just time picker

Tags: node.js, pug, bootstrap-datetimepicker, eonasdan-datetimepicker

The components shows only time picker:[image: only timer..calender not showing.img]

```
.form-group
    label.col-xs-5.control-label test field
    .col-xs-5
      #fromDate.input-group.date
        input.form-control(type='text')
          span.input-group-addon
          span.glyphicon.glyphicon-calendar
```

```js
$(function () {
  $('#fromDate').datetimepicker({
    sideBySide: true,
    locale:'en-ca'
  });
})
```

Why calendar is not showing?

Comment: Do you have custom css that affects the datetimepicker? The component has the [`debug`](https://eonasdan.github.io/bootstrap-datetimepicker/Options/#debug) option , if you set it to `true`, you can inspect datetimepicker parts and investigate further.

Answer (score 1):

it seems like you are using [eonasdan-datetimepicker](http://eonasdan.github.io/bootstrap-datetimepicker/)

I copied your template, and it is working as it should.

[Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/William_/q2oh2qeb/)

**HTML**

```
<div class="form-group">
  <label class='label col-xs-5 control-label test field'></label>
  <div class="col-xs-5">
    <div class='input-group date' id='myDatepicker'>
      <input type='text' class="form-control" />
      <span class="input-group-addon">
     <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-calendar"></span>
      </span>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

**JS Code**

```
$('#myDatepicker').datetimepicker({
  sideBySide: true,
  locale: 'en-ca'
});
```